# Golang: Wait x amount of time before looping again without starting new goroutine

Tags: go, time

I have a loop that needs to wait a random amount of time before looping again.

What I have:

```
for {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    r := rand.Int()
    //Do stuff
    t, _ := time.ParseDuration(string(r) + "ms")
    time.Sleep(t)
}
```

Unfortunately, the loops run multiple times, just like if `time.Sleep` was not working.

Comment: Only seed a PRNG once. I don't understand the rest, `time.Sleep()` doesn't start a new goroutine.

Comment: Okay. My //Do stuff is running once on the first iteration, twice on the second, three times on the third and so on...how would i make it only run once everytime?

Comment: This will also sleep for a random duration between 0ms and 292271 millenia (on a 64-bit system; up to 24 days on 32-bit), which seems like it's probably not what you want.

Comment: Nothing in the code quoted would cause the behavior you're describing, but there's not much to go on. Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem?

Comment: You are correct. Figured it out after realizing it wasn't the sleep. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You should check the error you are currently discarding from `t, _ := time.ParseDuration`: the `time.Duration` you are passing to Sleep is in its zero value, which causes the function to sleep for 0 nanoseconds.

### Change #1: handle the error

```
    t, err := time.ParseDuration(string(r) + "ms")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
```

Resulting in:

`time: invalid duration �ms`

Since you are directly casting an integer to a string, you are messing with a whole lot of unicode logic you don't really want to.

### Change #2: use `strconv`:

```
    t, err := time.ParseDuration(strconv.Itoa(r) + "ms")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
```

Result:

`time: invalid duration 7936209096285811603ms`

You get this error because `time.Duration` is represented using a `int64` for storing nanoseconds. You are trying to pass an `int` representing MILLIseconds: you will be overflowing most of the time.

### Change #3: directly assign to the Duration

```
for {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    r := rand.Int()
    log.Println(r)
    d := time.Duration(r)
    time.Sleep(d)
}
```

Now it works! The first integer generated by my function is 649508928394582529, which I am casting to `time.Duration` (again, this is an `int64` of nanoseconds).
This is approximatively 649508928 seconds: just over a week.

It looks like a lot. But keep in mind that you were trying to use the generated `int` as milliseconds: that is 10^6 times more.

### Change #4: Seed outside the loop

While we are at it, let's polish a bit:

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
for {
    r := rand.Int()
    log.Println(r)
    d := time.Duration(r)
    time.Sleep(d)
}
```

Explanation: a pseudorandom number generator is a state machine. You have to feed it a seed once, and then it will work forever. Giving it a different seed every time you run it is not improving its randomness: it's applying the same algorithm over and over on a predictable value (time). You can achieve the same exact degree of randomness by directly using `time.Now()Unix()`

Comment: I would also include `d := time.Duration(r) * time.Millisecond` in case the user needs the integer to be milliseconds. He may be limiting it somehow or the random part may be just for this question.

Answer (score 1):

`for` loop doesn't spawn new goroutines unless you do it explicitly in cycle. By default next cycle starts only after previous is done. So you do not need any delay. Just make sure you do not use `go` keyword in your cycle.

If you want to launch goroutines:

```
for {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    r := rand.Int()
    //Do stuff in separate goroutine
    go DoStuff()
    t, _ := time.ParseDuration(string(r) + "ms")
    time.Sleep(t)
}
```

This way new goroutine will be launched.